# Input devices not working at boot

Tags: boot, 13.04, keyboard, mouse

Well, I'm not sure if this is caused by Ubuntu, but it started to happen after I installed Ubuntu, so I decided to ask here...

Sometimes, when I turn my PC it goes to Grub and I cannot use my keyboard to select an OS to boot (I have Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 7 installed here), so it goes to the default OS, which is Windows 7. Once Windows starts, I can't use my mouse nor my keyboard, not even to turn my PC off (I have to do it from the Power Button)!

After turning my PC off and on again it goes back to normal, but still this happens to me about one out of five times I turn my PC on, any idea of what the cause might be? Thanks.

Comment: Could be the USB settings in BIOS/UEFI or hardware like USB hubs or KVM switches that causes this behaviour. Is the keyboard directly plugged into the computer? Is it a wireless keyboard?

Comment: @LiveWireBT Yes, it is directly plugged into the computer, and it is not wireless.

Comment: Then its likely to be the USB settings in BIOS that cause trouble, but you should also check with another keyboard or mouse when the issue appears. Have you tried looking for a BIOS/UEFI firmware update? May be it's a bug that has already been fixed by the manufacturer.